# SVG tooltip text getting cut off despite dynamic length

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, text

I'm trying to figure out why my SVG is cutting off the text in a tooltip.

Here's the XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg onload="init(evt)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="279px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300px;height:279px;background:#FFFFFF;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 279" width="300px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
    <defs>
        <filter height="300%" id="f1a2x7zkhg3k0o" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/>
            <feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <style>
    .tooltip{
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      fill:black;
    }
    .tooltip_bg{
      fill: yellow;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        <![CDATA[
    function init(evt){
      if ( window.svgDocument == null ){
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
      }
      tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
      tooltip_bg = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_bg');
    }
    function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext){
      var el = evt.target;
      var bbox = el.getBBox();
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +11);
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+27);
      tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
      length = tooltip.getComputedTextLength();
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",length+8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+11);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visibile");
    }
    function HideTooltip(evt){
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }
  ]]>
    </script>
    <g>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="224.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="90" x2="90" y1="41.6094" y2="235.3672"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="229" x2="229" y1="41.6094" y2="235.3672"/>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="138" x="19" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="124" x="26" y="26.5332">webAPICreateMode</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="138" x="19" y="234.3672"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="124" x="26" y="255.9004">webAPICreateMode</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="171" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="178" y="26.5332">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="171" y="234.3672"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="178" y="255.9004">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="224.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="293" x="0" y="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="293" y1="72.7852" y2="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="293" y1="75.7852" y2="75.7852"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="207" x="43" y="61.6094"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="193" x="49" y="79.1045">step 1: Account.Account Credit</text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="212.5,114.3125,222.5,118.3125,212.5,122.3125,216.5,118.3125" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="90" x2="218.5" y1="118.3125" y2="118.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="97" y="113.4561">1</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="59" x="108" y="113.4561">Divyaabca</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="5" y="131.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="9" y="148.8076">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, '(input = 123); (other = 456); ')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data</a> 1
        </text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="101,179.0156,91,183.0156,101,187.0156,97,183.0156" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="95" x2="228.5" y1="183.0156" y2="183.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="107" y="178.1592">2</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="118" y="178.1592">[200]</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f1a2x7zkhg3k0o)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="39" y="196.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← {{PATH2}} saveV ← {{PATH}}')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>
        </text>
        <!--MD5=[6ce68cb015799a4df6769e34b7f2eea5]
@startuml 
autonumber 
==step 1: Account.Account Credit== 
"webAPICreateMode"->"Web API Step 1": Divyaabca  
rnote left "webAPICreateMode"
static data 1
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 1"
"webAPICreateMode" <- - "Web API Step 1": [200] 
rnote over "webAPICreateMode"
validation data 1
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 1"
@enduml

PlantUML version 1.2021.8(Sat Jun 26 01:20:59 PDT 2021)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Default Encoding: UTF-8
Language: en
Country: US
-->
    </g>
    <rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" ry="2" width="55" height="21" visibility="hidden"/>
    <text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text>
</svg>
```

The tooltip in question is the one within this snippet:

```html
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← {{PATH2}} saveV ← {{PATH}}')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>
        </text>
```

I thought that my `ShowTooltip` function, in calling `tooltip.getComputedTextLength()` would compute the right required length. I tried experimenting with the style tags, increasing `textLength` and changing `lengthAdjust` but it didn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It's invisible where it overflows the viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson OOh I see! Is there a way to dynamically change that in the showTooltip method? For example, if it computes the required width (say its length + bbox.x) and it's greater than the viewbox width?

Comment: why not just make the viewBox bigger?

Comment: The file above is being generated through a program. To clarify, I'm using the [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/) library to export UML diagrams to an XML string, that writes to some file. So I sadly can't hard-code it

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to display all tooltips in a dedicated box (see some video games). The box could be in a fixed location and have static or dynamic dimensions. That way you'd have a reserved spot for popups and could style everything and plan the output accordingly.

You could even check the location of hovered element and if it's in the top half of the image, draw the tooltip box in the bottom half and vice versa.